# Toggling multiple divs classes with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Considering the following scenario:

- There are a series os divs, all with the class `.step`
- The quantity of `div.step`s can be 3 or greater.

I need to toggle the classes `.current`, `.next` and `.previous` every 5 seconds within all the `div.step` . There always must be one `.current`, one `.next` and one `.previous`.

If `.current` is the first one, the second one will be `.next` and the last one `.previous`.

If `.current` is the last one, the one before will be `.previous` and the first will be `.next`.

Otherwise, they always will be in order `.previous`, `.current` and `.next`.

I'm having trouble with this code. Please provide help or ideas.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
    // Initial Setup
    $(".step:nth-of-type(1)").addClass("current");
    $(".step:nth-of-type(2)").addClass("next");
    $(".step:last-of-type").addClass("previous");

    var steps = $(".step");

    setInterval(changeClasses, 5000);  
    
  
    function changeClasses(){

     for(var i = 0; i < steps.length; i++){
      // if current is first
      // first : current
      // second : next
      // last : previous


      // if current is last
      // last : current
      // first : next
      // last - 1 : previous

     }
    }  

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section class="steps-wrapper">
  <div class="step">Step 1</div>
  <div class="step">Step 2</div>
  <div class="step">Step 3</div>
  <div class="step">Step 4</div>
  <div class="step">Step 5</div>
</section>
```

Comment: you can try with https://api.jquery.com/index/ this will give you the index of specific element, so if index of current is 0 then 1 will be next and total-count will be previous , if index i is equal total count then 0 will be next and count-1 will be last. also index is zero bases so keep in mind that you have to subtract -1 from total count for last element index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just allocate the values of `current`, `previous`, and `next` to a variable and increment those in the setInterval method, then if it exceeded the number of steps while incrementing, assign it with 0.

```
var steps = $(".step");
var numSteps = steps.length;
var current = 0;
var next = 1;
var previous = numSteps - 1;

setInterval(changeClasses, 300);    

function changeClasses(){
    //increment the positions
    current = current === numSteps - 1 ? 0 : ++current;
    next = next === numSteps - 1 ? 0 : ++next;
    previous = previous === numSteps - 1 ? 0 : ++previous;

    //remove the classes
   steps.removeClass("current").removeClass("next").removeClass("previous");

    //add the classes
    $(steps[current]).addClass("current");
    $(steps[next]).addClass("next");
    $(steps[previous]).addClass("previous");
}
```

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vn66nmzy/1/).

You could of course improve this one, there are too many things left for improvement here.